# Sum of average column in PivotTable

Tags: excel, sum, average, pivot-table

I have a data column of averages. I need to put in "total" column the sum of these averages.

```
Average1: 200   
Average2: 400  
   Total: 600  (not 300)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, unless in the same column but outside the PivotTable. Note that if the averages are a VALUE field there is no guarantee that the average 'total' will be `300` anyway. This for much the same reason as adding averages may give a meaningless result.